Latex newline for equations without requiring align
How could I write the "refined arms" and "hand-object contact probability" portion of the equations in the next line without requiring them to be aligned to the "object motion probability" ?
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    L_3 &= \sum_{s,i,j,t} \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i}_{\mathclap{\text{object motion probability}}} \\
    &+ \lambda_1\underbrace{\delta_s^t\lVert(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t)\circ (1-m_s)\rVert_2^2}_\text{refined arms} 
     + \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \beta^t_{s,j}}_{\mathclap{\text{hand-object contact probability}}}
\end{align}
\end{document}


EDIT: I meant I just want to write the next two portions of the equation on the next line without having to align them like this
\begin{equation}
    L_3 = \sum_{s,i,j,t} \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i}_{\mathclap{\text{object motion probability}}} \\
    + \lambda_1\underbrace{\delta_s^t\lVert(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t)\circ (1-m_s)\rVert_2^2}_\text{refined arms} + \lambda_2\underbrace{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \beta^t_{s,j}}_{\mathclap{\text{hand-object contact probability}}}
\end{equation}

Using equation and \\ does not work.


Please specify what exactly you mean by next line here? It is not clear from the image

@daleif i have updated my post to explain better

gather instead of align would center the expressions.  But I think you do want them aligned, but not with the + under the =.  I would start your second line with &\qquad+.  Does that get you the output you want?

Although that still pushes the (2) out of the way.  There's not much room in that second line.  What do you want your output to be?

amsmath provides the multline environment that allows a split of lines like what you are looking for.

You can use multline or, probably better, aligned with three lines.
To get the second picture I added \usepackage{newtx}.
Beware that lettersize is not a recognixed option. Worth noting is the simplified input and how I avoided overlap in the first summation.
\documentclass[letterpaper,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ubracetext}{smm}{%
  {% avoid bad spacing
   \underbrace{#2}_{%
     \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\mathclap{\text{#3}}}{\text{#3}}%
   }%
  }
}

\begin{document}

Two lines for the display
\begin{multline}
L_3 = 
  \sum_{s,i,j,t}
  \ubracetext{\mathllap{\lambda_2}\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i}{object motion probability} \\
+ \lambda_1 \ubracetext{\delta_s^t\lVert(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t)\circ (1-m_s)\rVert_2^2}{refined arms}
+ \lambda_2 \ubracetext*{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \beta^t_{s,j}}{hand-object contact probability}
\end{multline}
but three lines might be better
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
L_3 &= 
  \sum_{s,i,j,t}
  \ubracetext{\mathllap{\lambda_2}\hat{\alpha}^t_i \log \alpha^t_i}{object motion probability}
\\
&+ \lambda_1 \ubracetext{\delta_s^t\lVert(\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s} - y^t)\circ (1-m_s)\rVert_2^2}{refined arms}
\\
&+ \lambda_2 \ubracetext*{\hat{\beta}^t_{s,j} \log \beta^t_{s,j}}{hand-object contact probability}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}




"Two lines" has the + shifted to the right of the =, which looks better IMO.  Would nesting aligned inside multlined inside equation allow "three lines" to have the same affect?

@Teepeemm + is right of = just by chance, because of the lengths.
